# Función que retorna arreglo de caracteres en c++

Tags: c++, array, char

Soy nuevo en c++. Una de mis primeras tareas es crear un juego de ahorcado. Para ello, tengo que crear una función que retorne un arreglo de guines bajos: _ _ _. Ese arreglo despues será parametro de otra función que remplazará los guiones bajos _ con letras como "a".

En este sentido, escribí la siguiente función en codeblocks que, al compilar arroja el error

> Invalid conversion from 'cont char*' to 'char'

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
char* completesTheWord(string word){
    char* foundLetters = new char[word.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++ ){
        foundLetters[i] = "_";
        cout << foundLetters[i];
    }

    return foundLetters;
}
```

El resultado esperado es que se imprima en consola:

```
_
_
_
_
```

Asimismo, mas adelante en el programa debería poder guardar el arreglo en un identificador:

```
char* arregloDeGuionesBajos = completesTheWord("hola")
```

Comment: Para comparar contra caracteres individuales, se usan **comillas simples** `'_'`.

Comment: Dios te bendiga

Comment: Claro porque los literales de string son del tipo `const char*`. Es diferente a `char`.